# Execute template without quotes in golang

Tags: go, template-engine

I'd like to execute template with `noescape` and no quotes, but `noescape` is not supported now.

Any suggestion or do I have to use another template engine? Thank you!

Code here: http://play.golang.org/p/R-Ib5H9bXx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are encouraged to store safe Javascript in the type **[`template.JS`](http://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#JS)**:

> type JS string
>
> JS encapsulates a known safe EcmaScript5 Expression,
>   for example, `(x + y * z())`. Template authors are responsible for
>   ensuring that typed expressions do not break the intended precedence
>   and that there is no statement/expression ambiguity as when passing an
>   expression like "{ foo: bar() }\n'foo'", which is both a valid
>   Expression and a valid Program with a very different meaning.

So, the only change you need to do to your code is:

```
type Var struct {
    Name  template.JS
    Value template.JS
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A small addition to @ANisus answer. There is also a similar wrapper for HTML (and CSS). Whenever you try to pass an HTML string into a template, it gets quoted. So in order to render the safe HTML properly, use:

```golang
yourHTML := "<strong>Hi!</strong>"
yourWrappedHTML := template.HTML(yourHTML)
// pass the later into your template
```